# Bootstrap layout splitting

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Please help i need bootstrap layout design. I need layout design like the attachment image format. I need one page splitted to two column (header and content with scroll bar) and another column splitted by two rows with responsive. I tried all but not working. Please help

[image: layout needed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here ... https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/

In general, building a layout begins with a container element. The container defines a 12 column grid system. Read more about this here ... https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Each column is given a class with the naming convention, col-{breakpoint}-{# of columns}

Here is a example of a three column layout. The first and last .col will span 3 column units, while the middle will span 6.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      FIRST COLUMN
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      SECOND COLUMN
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      THIRD COLUMN
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have fun coding!

Comment: The new docs are at http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/. I recommend checking them.